# 404 Page not Found DURING Web Deploy with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, publish, http-status-code-404

I always get a 404 error, accessing my production web site ***during*** the publishing process using the 1-click publish ob Visual Studio 2010. After the publishing process finished everything works fine. Isn't there anything like the appoffline.htm feature, ASP.NET supports?

Markus